# R - Using rvest when html end tag in wrong place

Tags: html, rvest

I am trying to scrape a website with a login. This should be easy using rvest code along the lines of:

```
url <- "https://badsite.com/users/login"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(read_html(pgsession))[[1]] 
filled_form <- set_values(pgform, email="*****", password="*****")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

However, the target web page has been poorly constructed and there is an html end tag `</html>` in the wrong place and it looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
  </head>
</html>
  <body>
   <div class="container" id="Login_page">
   ...
     <form method="post" action="."><input type='hidden' ...
   ...
   </div>
  </body>
```

My use of rvest (v0.3.2) is currently leading to ...

```
Error in html_form(read_html(pgsession))[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

... which I put down to the full html file not being read in.

How can I use R code to elegantly ignore the premature end tag and submit a filled form from the otherwise ignored html body section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A find and replace of the offending item does the trick:

```
pgsession$response$content <- charToRaw(gsub("<!-- <!","\n</html><!-- <!",(gsub("\n</html>","",httr::content(pgsession$response, as="text")))))
```